# Powerbeats 3 can connect to windows 10 but set as speakers instead of headset, but the sound still on pc speaker

Tags: windows-10, laptop, bluetooth, speakers, headset

My Powerbeats 3 (wireless headphone) can connect and works property as Bluetooth headset as named as "Powerbeats3" previously. After I formatted and replaces hard disk in my laptop, my Powerbeats can pair to the laptop but connected as speakers with a different name "SPACE 7". Even though can connect, my Powerbeats doesnt make any sound but the laptop turns its own speaker. I tried to uninstall it several times but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the volume icon in the taskbar and try tweaking options such as volume mixer and sound settings. Or try the troubleshooter if all fails.